# How can I get Payments Details In an block below Order Summary in Checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, custom, knockoutjs

I know the way to get the block but not about the payment info.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my below line for this. Hope this will help, and if it is please mark this as answer.

https://gist.github.com/sdverma/f34f666241ba3c896a71d2b3d8dad8db

Comment: Can you add the code here rather than a link please? Links may result in a 404 if they get removed whereas the code on the answer will remain and can be edited if needs be.

Comment: Getting issue with putting code here that's why i have added the link.

Comment: @SandeepVerma  module is not working it does not reflect the changes.

Comment: Have you clear the cache?

Comment: Yes and changes are not reflected

Comment: I tried on magento 2.3.5-p1 also and it is working good for me.

@Tanmay Can you confirm that the module is registered in you setup?

Comment: @SandeepVerma I also need something like this tried your solution but its not working for 
2.3.4,2.3.5 or 2.4.3